# Calling a function which is declared under the current function

Tags: c

I'm a newcomer to C and  I have a problem when trying to call a function which is declared under the current function
Ex:

```
void test (){ test1 ();}
void test1(){ }
```

I could just move test1 above test, but I have this as well :

```
void test () {test1 ()}
void test4 () {test ()}
void test3 () {test4 ()}
void test1 () {test3 ()}
```

So do you see that If I moved test() I will have the same problem for test4 () ?
What could I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C will parse your file from top to bottom.  It needs to at least understand the signature of a function before it can verify it's use.  This is why you are running into the problem you have.

If you want to tell C about a function before it's defined you need to prototype the function.  This is essentially adding the signature of the function to the file for C to process.

For example you can prototype test1 with the following

```
void test1();
```

Then you can call it before it's defined

```
void test1();
void test() { test1(); }
void test1() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is "forward declare" your functions before defining them. As in:

```
// Declarations
void test();
void test1();

// Definitions
void test()
{ 
   // definition using test1
}

void test1()
{
   // definition using test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void test();
void test1();
void test3();
void test4();

void test () {test1 ()}
void test4 () {test ()}
void test3 () {test4 ()}
void test1 () {test3 ()}
```

In C, you can't use a function unless it is defined *before* your function. This is how C works. In most other languages the compiler takes care of that. This is called forward declaration. You are just telling the compiler if you see `test`, `test1`, `test3`, `test4` in my code don't produce an error, because these functions are defined elsewhere not before my function.

Comment: It's not required to _define_ a function before the call, it's required to _declare_ it.  And even then, if you don't declare it, it will be implicitly declared as int function(); which is OK (but not good practice) if that declaration is compatible with the definition.

Comment: I meant if you don't want to declare it you have to define it before your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare function prototypes:

```
void test();
void test1();
void test3();
void test4();

void test () {test1 ();}
void test4 () {test ();}
void test3 () {test4 ();}
void test1 () {test3 ();}
```

Answer (score 0):

you first let compiler know the function exist :)